# Tiling with limited number of tiles.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, tiling

Consider a $2 \times n$ grid that is to be tiled with up to $n$ tiles of dimensions $2\times 1$ and up to two tiles of dimensions $2\times 2$. Rotation of tiles is not allowed. In how many ways can this tiling of the grid be done?

**My work**

I was able to work out a recurrence to find $T_n$, the number of ways to tile a $2\times n$ grid with tiles of given dimensions without constraints on number of tiles used.

$$T_n = T_{n-1} + 2T_{n-2}$$
with $T_1=1$, $T_2=2$

However I am unable to work out the constraint on the number of tiles.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why did you say $2T_{n-2}$ instead of $T_{n-2}$ ?

Comment: When there are $2$ columns left to be tiled, one will have two ways of filling them: $2$ $1\times 2$ tiles or $1$ $ 2\times 2$ tile.

Comment: sorry, i missed that part in the question

Comment: Have you tried first looking at what happens when you have zero $2\times 2$ tiles, or at most one $2 \times 2$ tile?  Those are good warmups, and their answers might help you compute this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you cannot rotate, the $2\times$ might as well be $1\times$ throughout. Once you place the big tiles, there is only one way to complete the tiling, so you can just  count the numbers of packings of $0$, $1$, or $2$ big tiles.  For $0$ big tiles, there is only $1$.  For $1$ big tile, you have $n-1$ choices.  For $2$ big tiles, you have $\binom{n-1}{2}-(n-2)$ choices if $n \ge 2$.